# DevExtreme chart update on angularjs directive - just last created chart updates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, devexpress, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to update multiple DevExtreme charts. Each chart is bounded to chat Settings on a directive isolated scope. The directive scope datasource is bound to the app controller model on its scope. Everything works for one chart being updated, but when it has more the one, just the last created is being updated.

Follows my directive code

```
app.directive('prismaHistogram', function () {
    var directiveDefinitionObject = {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            name:  '@',
            model: '=',
            id: '=id',
            deleteFunction: '&',
        },
        replace: false,
        templateUrl: './directives/prismaHistogram.html',
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            $scope.refresh = function(model){

                $scope.model = model;
                $scope.datasource = [];

                $scope.model.stats.avg = parseFloat($scope.model.stats.avg).toFixed(2).toString();

                $scope.model.bins.forEach(function (bin, indxex) {
                    var temp = { Label: bin.label, Freq: +bin.count };
                    $scope.datasource.push(temp);
                });

                $scope.serviceChartSettings = {
                    //dataSource: $scope.datasource,
                    adaptiveLayout: {
                        keepLabels: false,
                    },
                    legend: {
                        visible: false
                    },
                    size: {
                        height: 250
                    },
                    argumentAxis: {
                        axisDivisionFactor: 30
                    },
                    series: {
                        argumentField: "Label",
                        valueField: "Freq",
                        //name: "My oranges",
                        type: "bar",
                        color: '#005b82'
                    },
                    bindingOptions: {
                        dataSource: 'datasource'
                    }
                };

                //$scope.$apply(function () {
                //    // force chartjs refresh
                //});

            }

            $scope.$watch('model', function (newModelVal, oldModelVal){
                $scope.refresh(newModelVal);
            });      //attaches an watcher to model to do grid refresh

            //$scope.$watch('model', $scope.refresh());      //attaches an watcher to model to do grid refresh

            $scope.onCloseClick = function () {
                $scope.deleteFunction({ id: $scope.id });
            };

            $scope.refresh($scope.model);
        }]
    }

    return directiveDefinitionObject;
});
```

Dev suggests to do updates using Data Stores and encapsulating the refresh explicitly inside and $apply(function(){}) call, which won't work for me because the event which fires the chart update is a scope variable change, which is already done inside an apply(). I've tried to use the store but the result was the same

Is this a DevExtreme chart bug? Can anyone see a workaround? Thanks, everybody.